# Return message if I get needed array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

My [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jyKjMz). I'm trying to output a message if I get needed element from array.

JavaScript:

```
function GetValue()
{
    var myarray = new Array("word1","word2","word3","word4","word5");
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
};
//rand array element

var clicks = 0;
function onClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
};
//count clicks

function printMessage(random, clicks) {
  if (random === "word1") {
    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML =
    "you get " + random + "after " + clicks + "clicks";
  }
}
//display "you get word1 after _ clicks"
```

Comment: You'll want to call printMessage from  inside GetValue, so you can pass it the random word from the array. If you want to use the amount of clicks as well, merge your onClick function into the GetValue function, or make one of the other call the other. You're calling two seperate functions in the html `onclick="GetValue();onClick"`, so if you would merge them or have one call the other, you could use the clicks as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should invoke `printMessage` function  in `onClick` method.

```
function onClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    printMessage(document.getElementById("message").innerHTML,clicks);
};
```

Here is solution:

```js
function GetValue()
{
    var myarray = new Array("word1","word2","word3","word4","word5");
    var random = myarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * myarray.length)];
   document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=random;
}; //rand array element

var clicks = 0;
function onClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    printMessage(document.getElementById("message").innerHTML,clicks);
}; //count clicks

function printMessage(random, clicks) {
  if (random === "word1") {
    document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML =
    "you get " + random + " after " + clicks + " clicks";
  }
} //display "you get word1 after _ clicks"
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="GetValue();onClick()" />
<p id="message"></p>

<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>

<p id="alert"></p>
```

Comment: thanks! next i'll try to make a page reload after use get needed msg